# In fullcalendar event tooltip is not visisble

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, tooltip, fullcalendar-4

In my laravel 5.8 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 / jquery jQuery v3.3.1 fullcalendar v4.3.1 app I want to add tooltip to events of fullcalendar
and looking at this sample https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001

I do it as :

```
eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
    console.log("eventInfo" )
    console.log( eventInfo )

    console.log("eventInfo.el" )
    console.log( eventInfo.el )

   var tooltip = new Tooltip(eventInfo.el, {        
        title: 'Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor', //eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
    });

    eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML += "<i class='fa fa-external-link pull-right'" +
        " onclick=\"javascript:backendEvent.editCalendarEvent(event," + eventInfo.event.id + "); return" +
        " false;\">Edit</i>";

    return;
```

I have no any errors in console and no tooltip text.

and in console I see eventInfo.el as : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLi31.jpg
I suppose they are valid elements

In my resources/views/admin/event/index.blade.php I have included :

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/core/main.js') }}"></script>
<!-- FullCalendar Core Package v4.3.1 -->


<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js') }}"></script>
<!-- FullCalendar Day Grid Plugin v4.3.0 -->


<script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<!--   Copyright (C) Federico Zivolo 2019 -->    


<script src="{{ asset('js/tooltip.min.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Copyright (C) Federico Zivolo 2019 -->
In the example I see that tooltip var is created but never used . Is it ok ?

How to fix it ?
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

All js functionality is in public/js/defaultBS41Backend/admin/event.js file and it is loaded after fullcalendar files :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiO2Z.jpg

FullCsalendar is inited in js functions :

```
backendEvent.prototype.evenstLoadWithFullCalendar = function () {
    var dataArray = {
        "_token": this_csrf_token,
        "filter_event_name": $("#filter_event_name").val(),
        "filter_start_date": $("#filter_start_date").val(),
        "filter_end_date": $("#filter_end_date").val(),
        "filter_type": $("#filter_type").val(),
        "filter_status": $("#filter_status").val()
    }

    var href = this_backend_home_url + "/admin/get_events_fc_listing";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: href,
        data: dataArray,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error_code == 0) {
                initFullCalendar(response.events);
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            popupErrorMessage(error.responseJSON.message)
        }
    });

}


function initFullCalendar(eventsList) {
    if (typeof window.calendarEventsObject != "undefined") { // clear existing instance
        window.calendarEventsObject.destroy();
    }

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('events_calendar');

    var effective_device_width = effectiveDeviceWidth('width') //TODO

    window.calendarEventsObject = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['dayGrid'],

        eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
            console.log("eventInfo" )
            console.log( eventInfo )

            console.log("eventInfo.el" )
            console.log( eventInfo.el )

           var tooltip = new Tooltip(eventInfo.el, {        // example : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo
                // title: eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description,
                title: 'Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  tempor', //eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
            });

            eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-title').innerHTML += "<i class='fa fa-external-link pull-right'" +
                " onclick=\"javascript:backendEvent.editCalendarEvent(event," + eventInfo.event.id + "); return" +
                " false;\">Edit</i>";

        },

        events: eventsList,
        // events: [],

        header: {
            left: 'LEFT98',
            center: 'title123',
            right: 'Right 444'
        },

        showNonCurrentDates: false,

        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        fixedWeekCount: false,

        aspectRatio: 0.4,
        height: 700,

        select: function (start, end) {
            alert( "select:::"+var_dump(-50) )
            var title = "Available";
            var evid = SaveEvent(start, end, '1');
            $('#events_calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },

        eventClick: function (clickObj) {
            alert( "eventClick clickObj.el::"+var_dump(clickObj.el) )
            if (clickObj.el.href != "") {
                // alert( "::"+var_dump(-4) )
                let el_href = clickObj.el.href
                clickObj.el.href = ""
                window.open(el_href, "_blank");
                // clickObj.event.preventDefault();
                alert( "::"+var_dump(-41) )
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        },
    });

    window.calendarEventsObject.render(
        {
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            textColor: 'yellow',
        }
    );

    jQuery('.eo-fullcalendar').on('click', '.fc-event', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    });

}   // function initFullCalendar() {
```

I know that when data are loaded with ajax (as in my case) it can raise issue
with some jquery  components. Can it be that after I loaded data with ajax I have to init tooltip 1 more time?

Comment: Did you also include the related CSS for the tooltip in your code?

Comment: Could you please to point which css styles did I miss?
here https://prnt.sc/ozhd18 I used 2 styles from links
Something else ?

I suppose I provided invalid url, I looked at this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo  demo.

Comment: I saved a copy of fullCalendar's demo CodePen: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYOEYdp?editors=0110 . If you look in the main CSS section (as opposed to the links) you'll see what I mean. Of course you can customise it to your liking.

Comment: I inserted your css code, but it did not help, I have no tooltip.
Could you please to look at live https://www.votes.my-demo-apps.tk/admin/events
The credentials are on login page, click “Search” button on pages opened.

Comment: it's really hard to tell because there is so much other stuff on the page. Can you tell where in your files you have got the fullCalendar setup code, and also whereabouts you added the CSS for the tooltip?

Comment: P.S. from what I can see, you appear to have included jQuery twice in your page - once through `https://www.votes.my-demo-apps.tk/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`(v.3.3.1)   and once through `https://www.votes.my-demo-apps.tk/js/defaultBS41Backend/admin/event.js?dt=1567161110`(v1.12.4) . Both are added via script tags in your page. It may not be the cause of this specific issue but it can lead to conflicts and unexpected behaviour. You only need one copy, probably the newer one.

Comment: I do not see 2nd reference to jQuery. Where did you find it ? Sure it is not what we need.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: I found the 2nd jQuery reference in a script tag near the bottom the page. It points to this URL: `https://www.votes.my-demo-apps.tk/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1553506748`. If you visit that URL it turns out to be a copy of jQuery 1.12.4. Sorry I think I told you the wrong URL in my last comment.

Comment: Anyway thanks for the extra information, but you still haven't told me where in your files you added that custom CSS for the tooltip? That's the crucial part.

Comment: P.S. Regardless of the above, it seems are you are already using bootstrap? If so then I don't think you actually need tooltip.js or the custom CSS, because bootstrap already provides popover and tooltip functionality - see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/ . It relies on popper.js (same as tooltip.js) does, but the CSS and script files are available via bootstrap already. So probably you can do it that way more easily than what you're trying right now.

Comment: P.P.S. you asked `Can it be that after I loaded data with ajax I have to init tooltip 1 more time?` ...no because `eventRender` runs after the event has downloaded. So you are not adding the tooltip until the event element already exists - in fact you are attaching it directly to the element object, so this is clearly not going to be an issue. The problem with ajax loading occurs when elements are created _after_ a function has been executed (e.g. to set an event handler) on a selector which would match the new element - if the element didn't exist when the function ran, it can't target it

Comment: 1)I put custom css into ends of https://www.votes.my-demo-apps.tk/css/defaultBS41Backend/backend.css?dt=1567173340
file, which is uploaded before public/js/defaultBS41Backend/admin/event.js.
https://imgur.com/a/9j89tqo
Can it be the issue ?

2) I removed 2nd jQuery reference by switching Debugging tool bar, but it did not help.

3)  If that is possible to tie event with bootstrap tooltip functionality, how can I make it, as I have eventInfo and eventInfo.el ?

Comment: I moved custom css into resources/views/defaultBS41Backend/admin/event/index.blade.php (page with fullcalendar) - still no effect

Comment: I expect you would use the popover something like `$(eventInfo.el).popover(...` and then add options as per the bootstrap documentation. That page I gave you the link to has examples. or you can use the tooltip variant: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ which is closer to what tooltip.js does. But setup is very similar again (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#usage specifically).

Comment: By the way it's quite possible that your tooltip CSS is not working because there may be a conflict with some rules relating to tooltips and popovers in Bootstrap (since it also relies on popper.js). I vaguely remember a question on this site a while back where someone had a similar issue. All the more reason to just use the bootstrap version instead...

Comment: With hints above I hide prior tooltip calling and tried :

            $(eventInfo.el).title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>"
            $(eventInfo.el).tooltip('show')
I did not help.
I do not know if I have to set properirs
data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" programmatically ?

Comment: No but you do need to set the tooltip up with the correct options before you call anything else like the show() method. Again the bootstrap documentation does explain that - it's right there at the top of the "usage" section I linked to! in fact if you just want the tooltip to show when the user hovers over the element, then you don't even need to call show() at all.

Comment: Google around and you can find loads more tutorials and examples outside the official ones too, to help you understand how to use it. It's not hard to find, so there's no need to guess at the correct code, really. Here's really simple one: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=place-html-inside-a-tooltip (taken from here: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tooltips.php)

Comment: Great Thanks!
It was helpfull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid decision in my case was :

```
eventRender: function (eventInfo) {

    $(eventInfo.el).tooltip({                
        title: "<i class=\"fa fa-users\"></i>&nbsp;<b>"+eventInfo.event.extendedProps.attendees_count+"&nbsp;attendee(s)</b>" +
            " <br><smalUUl>"+eventInfo.event.extendedProps.description+"</smalUUl>",
        html: true,
    });

},
```

where description and attendees_count my custom fields sent to event.
Without any additive libs

Comment: Well it still requires bootstrap and jQuery which are not normally required by fullCalendar, so I don't think you can say it does not require extra libraries. Just because they were there before on your specific page doesn't mean they might not be "extra" for someone else reading this answer. Better just to say what the requirements are. You did mention them in the question though I suppose

Answer (score 1):

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
   $('.has-tooltip').tooltip({container:'#calendar',placement:'top'});
},
```

You can put eventAfterAllRender to show tooltip